# customizing the NSPredicateEditor

Tags: objective-c, customization, nspredicateeditor

I want to customize the `NSPredicateEditorRowTemplate`, but I needn't the subtraction sign in the first RowTemplate, the second, and the third, like the Finder application.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of what you're describing. From what I see, all the + and - buttons are all present in Finder's "Find" window.

Comment: ok.I have send a Email to you.

Answer (score 4):

If you tell the `NSPredicateEditor` that it cannot remove all the rows in the editor, then the editor will automatically remove the `(-)`  button when necessary.

You can do this by unchecking the "`Can Remove All Rows`" checkbox when editing the predicate editor in a xib, or by doing it programmatically with the [`-setCanRemoveAllRows:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSRuleEditor_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004576-CH1-SW30) method.